# Is the 'direction' considered, when determining the branching factor in bidirectional search?

Tags: search, branching-factors, bidirectional-search

If I am correct, the branching factor is the maximum number of successors of any node.

When I am applying bidirectional search to a transition graph like this one below

[image]

If 11 is the goal state and I start going backwards, is 10 considered as a successor of 5? Even if it does not leads me further to my start state 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I am correct, the branching factor is the maximum number of successors of any node

You are correct, they should also be the immediate ones:

[image: branching factor]

> If 11 is the goal state and I start going backwards, is 10 considered as successor of 5? Even if it do not leads me further to my start state 1?

**No, there is also a bit of misunderstanding of bidirectional search:** In bidirectional search you run **2** simultaneous searches, one forward from the initial state, and another one backwards from the goal(hoping they meet in the middle and save you steps), if actions are reversible ( going from node to node), the successor nodes become predecessors in one search and vice versa, and your goal becomes your initial state, in your case:

[image: bidirectional search]

#### Reference/source

[Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/), by S. Russell and P. Norvig.